# Chrome extension breaks CSS

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store, stylish, userstyles

I am making a Chrome extension to bring Material Design to the Web version of Google Calendar. I used Stylish and Tampermonkey to make the changes, but when I put everything together in a package and load the package into Chrome, a big part of the CSS seems to be totally broken!

The userstyle available here: https://userstyles.org/styles/126526/google-calendar-material-v3-0-beta

The userscript here: https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/18878-google-calendar-web-material

And the Chrome extension here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-calendar-web-mater/cecnjahdgcpkhdgjbmiellinjbpamjgb

The strange thing that not everything is broken.

Should I use !important on every css rule, or the problem is somewhere else? The JS seems to work fine.

When I use Stylish for the CSS and Tampermonkey for JavaScript:
[image]

When using Chrome extension:
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background/content/popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: While this is interesting, without enough code and information for us to duplicate the issue, we basically have to **guess** at what the causes might be. Please [edit] the question to provide both a [mcve] and enough information to duplicate the issue. While many of might have ideas about what *could be* causing this, **guesses** are usually not sufficient to actually provide an Answer.

Comment: Use devtools to debug your extension.